# Multithreading for download in Android

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

I've tested a bit about how to speed up multiple downloads.

This is a table that shows how fast download (using a Samsung Galaxy S1) from 2 to 10 images over different networks using a single thread or a new thread for each download.

```
        Multithread     SingleThread    
Images  Wifi    3g      Wifi    3g
   2    1,1     6,6     2,0     6,7
   4    1,7     8,0     5,2     9,6
   6    2,1     6,1     7,5     15,5
   8    2,3     7,1     10,2    20,0
   10   2,3     12,5    13,5    26,7
```

With those results shows that multithreading the download accelerates a lot the task.

Then I tried the same code but with a HTC Wildfire, the UI thread run much less fluid when the number of threads downloading is high.

I addapted my code for launching each Thread with low priority:

```
Thread t= new Thread{
       public void run(){
          download(image[i]);
       }
t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY)
t.start
```

But the problem persists. Is there a way of make those threads don't affect the UI thread so much? If not how can I detect and adapt the number of threads to the device thats running the app?

Thanks

Note:The ten images have different sizes so have no sense to read the table by columns

Comment: You should be using `AsyncTask` if you don't want to disrupt the so called 'UI thread'. Also, the HTC Wildfire is very bad for network downloads (in my opinion) - my wife has one and it takes 3-4 times longer to do the same network tasks as my HTC Desire.

Answer (score 2):

In Samsung phones for some reason the threads compete with UI thread for resources. Try setting thread priority to [background](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)...this will ensure the thread does not compete with UI thread and the good thing is it will work across all devices..If you look into the source code of asynctask, they set the thread priority to the above mentioned value

Answer (score 2):

For downloading, always use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which does exactly this (and will let you easily publish download completion, if desired).  Also, in terms of the UI feeling not feeling fluid, many things can contribute to that, other than threading.  Run your code with DDMS and verify you can't causing the GC to fire constantly if your test has anything else going on.

In my experience, setting the thread priority has had mixed results on Android in terms of getting better performance by setting it lower.  Async task seems to do this more consistently.