# ListView onItemClick not always reacting, Busy UIThread

Tags: android, events, listview, ui-thread

I have a *ListView* with 4 photos on each row, and a photo download manager handling the download of all those photos. I've limited the number of threads downloading my photos because I had way too much threads created on arrival on the ListView ( It used to be : 4 photos per row * 5 or 6 rows displayed => 20/25 Threads, and + if you scroll )

So the thing is the UI Thread gets busy, and when I click on my items while photos are loading, the *OnItemClickEvent* is sometimes skipped, and the user has to wait the end of the downloads of click like crazy.

Is there a way to avoid skipped event like that ?

**Update :**
I'm sending broadcast each time a photo has been downloaded, and *notifyDataSetChanged* on my *ListView* adapter.

Comment: Are you using the UI-thread to download the images?

Comment: No don't worry, but I'm sending broadcast to refresh the display, and I can see it's getting really busy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a **20/25 threads** for downloading images is something **bad idea**.

I think you have to use `AsyncTask` for downloading those images so your UIThread never blocked,

Also you can use Lazy loading list by **Fedor** [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList).

Look at [Lazy-Loading Images into a ListView on Android](http://evancharlton.com/thoughts/lazy-loading-images-in-a-listview)

SO Question [Android - How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

[Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Comment: Maybe my sentence ws not clear enough, I limited the number of threads, because it used to be as many threads as photos on the screen

Comment: Just create a simple AsyncTask in its doInBackground() method download images and after one image download completes use pubishProgress() and onProgressUpdate method to update it in your UI, In this manner your UI Thread never blocked..

Comment: From 20+ threads I think its difficult to handle broadcast for different threads..

Comment: hum, no I limited the number of threads, and even with 2 threads I lose event

Comment: And both threads are you starting from Main thread, Then what about the concurrency of thread?.. When both completes together..

Comment: Basically, I have a Thread managing a pool of threads with a limited number of threads inside; I use a ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,"KindOfBitmap"> to handle the photos queue and I have no issue with any thread neither concurrency issue

Comment: Also setting the thread priority has had mixed results on Android in terms of getting better performance by setting it lower. Is somewhat to benefit to you. But I don't think it.. Look at this blog http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Comment: I couldn't see the "setting the thread priority" in this link, but the article is really interesting

Comment: For priorities look at this so question [Multithreading for download in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964380/multithreading-for-download-in-android)

Comment: Thanks ! I also found this link quite interesting http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/05/limitations-of-asynctask.html, I'm using AsyncTask for my thread pool, which is probably wrong giving me strange side-effects. I'm gonna change this. Thanks